# How to show the content of an url on an extension's popup?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that gets the current page's URL and uses it to create and show a QR code that links to it with the below Google API.

*This is my popup.js*

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var tablink = tab.url;
});

document.write('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=' + tablink);
```

*and this is my manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "Qrit",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Instantly creates a QR Code that links to the current page.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

The problem is that the popup is simply blank.
I know almost nothing about Javascript, nor Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom said, with manifest version 2 you cant have inline scripts.  Also, `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is decapitated and you should use `chrome.tabs.query`.
Here's something to get you started....

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Qrit",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Instantly creates a QR Code that links to the current page.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='popup.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='message'>Getting Image....</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function onImageLoad() {
  var message = document.querySelector('#message');
  message.parentNode.removeChild(message);
}

function onImageError(e) {
  var message = document.querySelector('#message');
  message.innerText = 'Error getting image';
  e.srcElement.parentNode.removeChild(e.srcElement);
}

function onWindowLoad() {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
  }, function(tab) {
    var image = document.createElement('IMG');
    image.src = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=' + tab[0].url;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    image.onload = onImageLoad;
    image.onerror = onImageError;
  });
}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you write "manifest_version": 2,it doesn't allow inline script.Second,your popup code should write like this

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var tablink = tab.url;
document.write('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=' + tablink);
});
```